# List of different computer languages and how common they are

Tags: programming-languages, survey

What are all the computer languages that exist, and how many people use them?

Oh, and the VAX BASIC I used in the late 1980's was NOT the same as the BASIC on MS-DOS.  Fortran IV and Fortran 77 were also significantly different.  Hmmm... but if different versions are that much different, then perhaps it should be limited to current languages.  It might be interesting if to know more than 15 people ever used System-J, or if anyone did any serious programming in VAX-DCL, but it's of more value to know more about languages I might actually encounter.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=programming%20language%20popularity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this list:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_programming_languages

Comment: It's quite interesting, although a bit thin.  I searched for Flash, Cold Fusion, and VB Script, all of which we have in use at work right now, and all were missing.

Comment: Flash isn't a programming language, ColdFusion is in the list (without a space), though VBScript is legitimately missing.

Comment: @Scott Anderson: Flex then, instead of Flash.  Neither is listed, and if we're writing an application using it, it rather seems like it is a programming language.

Answer (score 2):

I am not exactly sure what you're looking for, but you may find these interesting:

- [TIOBE Programming Community Index for May 2009](http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html)
- [ohloh.net language comparison](http://www.ohloh.net/languages/compare)
- [Most Popular Programming Languages](http://www.devtopics.com/most-popular-programming-languages)
- [Programming Language Popularity](http://www.langpop.com/)
- [Sourceforge Programming Language Usage Graph (2000-2006)](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~flab/languages.html)

Comment: langpop.com (Programming Language Popularity) includes ohloh.net stats as one of its metrics.

Answer (score 1):

I find when comparing two languages popularity using [google trends](http://www.google.com/trends) is very interesting. It lets you see what kind of trends over time have show on google key words and plot multiple keywords. With some interesting results like...

- [Sqeak Vs. Smalltalk](http://www.google.com/trends?q=squeak%2C+smalltalk) (It appears smalltalk was in the lead but got passed up in 2004)
- [Cobol Vs. Fortran](http://www.google.com/trends?q=cobol%2C+fortran&ctab=0&geo=all&date=all&sort=0) - Both are trending down pretty fast...
- Python Vs. Perl - Search two different ways using [programming](http://www.google.com/trends?q=perl+programming%2C+python+programming&ctab=0&geo=all&date=all&sort=0) or [script](http://www.google.com/trends?q=perl+script%2C+python+script&ctab=0&geo=all&date=all&sort=0) as a keyword along with python or perl to prevent false positives for the word python not related to the language.
- [Autoit Vs. AutoHotKey](http://www.google.com/trends?q=autoit%2C+autohotkey&ctab=0&geo=all&date=all&sort=0) - Interestingly both trending up slowly.

If you come up with some good ones please post a comment with them. I used google trends to accurately predict the last two presidential elections so its likely to be a pretty good metric of actual attention given (if keywords are not ambiguous).

Answer (score 0):

According to me there are three types of computer languages. They are Machine level language, low level language and High level language

Answer (score 0):

Currently,I am working Swift programming language. As per my understanding, In any computer language, there are some stuff is common. 
For example, declare variables, implement If..then condition.
For basic concept you can get idea about it from [this](http://ghcgames.blogspot.in/2015/12/basic-of-any-computer-language.html).